# Get saved id from HABTM save

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm saving data into my table fine, but I want to get the ID of the HABTM record that was saved.

The saving array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [Following] => Array
        (
            [follows_uid] => 36
        )

)
```

So it's saving a new record in the followers_users table, with the user id of 1 and user id of the person being followed is 36. For each new record there's a new ID, but I can't use `$this->User->getInsertID();` or `$this->User->getLastInsertID();` as that returns the ID of the `[User]`.

After saving and running `pr($this->User->FollowersUser);` I get this:

```
AppModel Object
(
    [useDbConfig] => default
    [useTable] => followers_users
    [id] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [FollowersUser] => Array
                (
                    [16] => 
                )

        )
```

On this occasion the actual inserted id from looking at the database is `9`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: sry tried hard but not finding way. Will back to this ques later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the id of the new HABTM field, I'd just do a simple `find` call. It may not be the most efficient way but it will have guaranteed results:

```
$this->User->FollowersUser->find('first', array(
    'FollowersUser.user_id'     => $user_id,
    'FollowersUser.follows_uid' => $followers_id
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks, I might just end up doing this as there doesn't seem to be another logical way...!!

Comment: True, it doesn't seem logical, but it's the guaranteed way. Maybe you can adapt the `afterSave` function of the corresponding models and return the ids, or create a new function in the models that encapsulates this solution. It'll be the same functional solution, but prettier.